# How does a section gets linked to .liquid file?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Which line from the code links the particular section to the .liquid file in Shopify ?

or

If i have created a section but i want to link another .liquid file to that section, how do i do that ?

ex- i created a section named Logo-List and i created a .liquid file named logo-bar.liquid with code

```
<div class="page-width">
  {% if section.settings.title != blank %}
   <div class="section-header text-center">
    <h2>{{ section.settings.title | escape }}</h2>
   </div>
  {% endif %}

  {% if section.blocks.size > 0 %}
    <ul class="logo-bar{% if section.settings.title_enable %} logo-bar--large{% endif %}">
    {% for block in section.blocks %}
      <li class="logo-bar__item{% if section.settings.title_enable %} logo-bar__item-- 
       large{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
        {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
            <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}" class="logo-bar__link">
            {% endif %}
           {% if block.settings.image != blank %}
            {{ block.settings.image | img_url: '160x160', scale: 2 | img_tag: 
         block.settings.image.alt, 'logo-bar__image' }}
         {% else %}
           {{ 'logo' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
          {% endif %}
           {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
            </a>
          {% endif %}
          </li>
         {% endfor %}
         </ul>
        {% endif %}

        {% if section.blocks.size == 0 %}
         {% include 'no-blocks' %}
         {% endif %}
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Shopify themes, you can only include a file if it is in your `/snippets` folder - so keep that in mind. Make sure your file `logo-bar.liquid` is in `/snippets`. Then you can simply write
`{% include 'logo-bar' %}`
to render that snippet inside this section.

Comment: Right now i have 1 single file for 2 logo sections in the /sections, so you are saying that i should create 1 more .liquid file in /snippets and {% include 'logo-bar' %} and after that if i edit anything into the /section file it will not reflect in /snippet file ?

Comment: I think you need to render the snippets file inside the section file.

Comment: Like the `no-blocks` is already used in your section code. https://prnt.sc/10b4g3h

Comment: Importing the snippet into the section means that any changes to the snippet will render inside the section. 

Not sure exactly what you're asking here: "after that if i edit anything into the /section file it will not reflect in /snippet file ?" You would want the snippet rendering inside the section, so editing the section would not affect the snippet.